# Trying to get to grips with ZIO

Tags: scala, functional-programming, zio

I'm just trying to learn ZIO and everything was going great guns until I ended up with a `Seq[URIO[Any, Fiber.Runtime[Throwable, Unit]]]` - I'm not really sure what to do with that - None of my Fibres are running, probably because I need to evaluate each `URIO` but if that is the case, how do I do that in the `zio.App`? I have tried mapping over the sequence but then I seem to keep ending up with `Seq[Nothing]`...

I have tried wrapping the Seq in an effect but that doesn't seem to help me. I have looked at the examples on the ZIO website but they don't deal with list of fibers so now I'm lost...

EDIT

OK - I guess my question is: How do I run a list of effects?

```
package testmesomemore

import zio._
import zio.console._
import zio.internal.Platform

import java.io.IOException

case class testme(
                   s: String,
                   n: Int,
                   l: String) {
  def runme() = UIO.effectTotal {
    println(s"${s}${l}")
  }
}

object mytest extends zio.App {

  override val platform: Platform = zio.Runtime.default.platform.withReportFailure(_ => ())
  def run(args: List[String]) = {

    val testlist: Seq[testme] = List[testme](testme("Hi there", 1, "."), testme("This is a test", 3, "..."))

    val result = for {

      // r <- testlist.map(d => d.runme().forkDaemon) // How to run a list of effects?

      a <- testme("Hi there", 1, ".").runme().forkDaemon
      b <- testme("This is a test", 3, "...").runme().forkDaemon

    } yield()

    result.exitCode
  }
}
```

I can fork the effects individually but if I have a list of them how would I fork them all?

I think I have been looking at this too long and now nothing makes sense... Sorry If I'm being dim and missing the obvious?

Comment: You probably want some kind of `traverse` instead of a `map` somewhere. But **ZIO** doesn't use standard names, I believe they have it as `ZIO.foreach` or something like that.

Comment: Can you please post an [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unless you have some specific need to manage fibers, just use Zio.foreach or ZIO.foreachPar for parallel, like so

```
ZIO.foreachPar(testlist)(_.runme()).exitCode
```